# JavaScript Object to JSON using python

Tags: python, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to retrieve what initially looked like a normal JSON from a website. But it is a JavaScript object which is not a valid JSON.
Is there a way to convert this string to JSON using python?

Example would be:

```
{
 firstName:"John",
 lastName:"Doe",
 age:50,
 eyeColor:"blue",
 dimensions:[
     {
      height: "2",
      width: "1"
     }
]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a parser with a non-strict mode that can handle such input. I've been recommending [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) for stuff like this, since it's the first viable candidate that came up when I searched for `python non-strict json parser`.

```
>>> demjson.decode("""{
...  firstName:"John",
...  lastName:"Doe",
...  age:50,
...  eyeColor:"blue",
...  dimensions:[
...      {
...       height: "2",
...       width: "1"
...      }
... ]
... }""")
{u'eyeColor': u'blue', u'lastName': u'Doe', u'age': 50, u'dimensions': [{u'width
': u'1', u'height': u'2'}], u'firstName': u'John'}
```

Comment: Dead link. Now at https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson and pretty inactive.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that Python does not understand JavaScript. If you can use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), it is easy to convert the input to JSON.

**Edit:** Of course you can also use the JavaScript console of every browser to do this.

```
> d = {
...  firstName:"John",
...  lastName:"Doe",
...  age:50,
...  eyeColor:"blue",
...  dimensions:[
...      {
.....       height: "2",
.....       width: "1"
.....      }
... ]
... };
{ firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: 'blue',
  dimensions: [ { height: '2', width: '1' } ] }
> JSON.stringify(d)
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","age":50,"eyeColor":"blue","dimensions":[{"height":"2","width":"1"}]}'
```